# TensorFlow, how to reuse a variable scope name

Tags: tensorflow

I defined a class here

```py
class BasicNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, scope, task_name, is_train=False, img_shape=(80, 80)):
        self.scope = scope
        self.is_train = is_train
        self.task_name = task_name
        self.__create_network(scope, img_shape=img_shape)

    def __create_network(self, scope, img_shape=(80, 80)):
        with tf.variable_scope(scope):
            with tf.variable_scope(self.task_name):
                with tf.variable_scope('input_data'):
                    self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, *img_shape, cfg.HIST_LEN], dtype=tf.float32)
                with tf.variable_scope('networks'):
                    with tf.variable_scope('conv_1'):
                        self.conv_1 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.inputs, num_outputs=32,
                                                  kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=4, padding='SAME', trainable=self.is_train)
                    with tf.variable_scope('conv_2'):
                        self.conv_2 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_1, num_outputs=64,
                                                  kernel_size=[4, 4], stride=2, padding='SAME', trainable=self.is_train)
                    with tf.variable_scope('conv_3'):
                        self.conv_3 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_2, num_outputs=64,
                                                  kernel_size=[3, 3], stride=1, padding='SAME', trainable=self.is_train)
                    with tf.variable_scope('f_c'):
                        self.fc = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(self.conv_3), 512,
                                                       activation_fn=tf.nn.elu, trainable=self.is_train)
```

And I want to define two instances of BasicNetwork with different task names. The scope is 'global'. But when I check the output, there are

```
ipdb> for i in net_1.layres: print(i)
Tensor("global/simple/networks/conv_1/Conv/Relu:0", shape=(?, 20, 20, 32), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)
Tensor("global/simple/networks/conv_2/Conv/Relu:0", shape=(?, 10, 10, 64), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)
Tensor("global/simple/networks/conv_3/Conv/Relu:0", shape=(?, 10, 10, 64), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)
Tensor("global/simple/networks/f_c/fully_connected/Elu:0", shape=(?, 512), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)

ipdb> for i in net_2.layres: print(i)
Tensor("global_1/supreme/networks/conv_1/Conv/Relu:0", shape=(?, 20, 20, 32), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)
Tensor("global_1/supreme/networks/conv_2/Conv/Relu:0", shape=(?, 10, 10, 64), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)
Tensor("global_1/supreme/networks/conv_3/Conv/Relu:0", shape=(?, 10, 10, 64), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)
Tensor("global_1/supreme/networks/f_c/fully_connected/Elu:0", shape=(?, 512), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2)
```

As you can see in the output, a new scope `global_1` has been created, but I want to make it `global`.  I set `reuse=True` but later I found that when there is no scope named `global`, `reuse=True` can't be used. What should I do?

Comment: I think this question is answered here after the fact: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285112/how-can-you-re-use-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow-without-a-new-scope-being-crea/49287805#49287805

Answer (score 0):

using `reuse` True you can get the existing variables. Now to reuse variables hose should exist in the graph. If th variables with same name exists, then you can reuse those for other operation.

```
class BasicNetwork(object):
def __init__(self, scope, task_name, reuse, is_train=False, img_shape=(80, 80)):
    self.scope = scope
    self.is_train = is_train
    self.reuse = reuse
    self.task_name = task_name
    self.__create_network(scope, reuse=self.reuse, img_shape=img_shape)

def __create_network(self, scope, reuse=None, img_shape=(80, 80)):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=reuse):
    ...
        # delete this line with tf.variable_scope(self.task_name): 
        # or replace with; with tf.name_scope(self.task_name):               

trainnet = BasicNetwork('global', taskname, None)
# resue the created variables
valnet = BasicNetwork('global', taskname, True)
```

Comment: Hi, the tasknames are different, one is 'simple' and another one is 'supreme'.

Comment: that won't effect the main logic. I just write that same for illustrations.

Comment: Sorry, but error occured, `ValueError: Variable global/supreme/networks/conv_1/Conv/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
`. Code is
`net_1 = BasicACNetwork('global', 'simple', reuse=None); net_2 = BasicACNetwork('global', 'supreme', reuse=True)`

Comment: to `reuse` variables, it should exist in the graph; it seems from the erros msgs the variables aren't created inside the graph.

Comment: Yes, that is because `global/supreme...` is not created. There is just `global/simple...` in the graph.

Comment: yes! since you want to use the same variables, keep their name identical, by removing the scope `with tf.variable_scope(self.task_name):`