# How can you re-use a variable scope in tensorflow without a new scope being created by default?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensor

I have created a variable scope in one part of my graph, and later in another part of the graph I want to add OPs to an existing scope. That equates to this distilled example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope('myscope'):
  tf.Variable(1.0, name='var1')

with tf.variable_scope('myscope', reuse=True):
  tf.Variable(2.0, name='var2')

print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])
```

Which yields:

```
['myscope/var1/initial_value', 
 'myscope/var1', 
 'myscope/var1/Assign', 
 'myscope/var1/read', 
 'myscope_1/var2/initial_value', 
 'myscope_1/var2', 
 'myscope_1/var2/Assign', 
 'myscope_1/var2/read']
```

My desired result is:

```
['myscope/var1/initial_value', 
 'myscope/var1', 
 'myscope/var1/Assign', 
 'myscope/var1/read', 
 'myscope/var2/initial_value', 
 'myscope/var2', 
 'myscope/var2/Assign', 
 'myscope/var2/read']
```

I saw this question which didn't seem to have an answer that addressed the question directly: [TensorFlow, how to reuse a variable scope name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614045/tensorflow-how-to-reuse-a-variable-scope-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one straightforward way to do this using `as` with `somename` in a context manager. Using this `somename.original_name_scope` property, you can retrieve that scope and then add more variables to it. Below is an illustration:

```
In [6]: with tf.variable_scope('myscope') as ms1:
   ...:   tf.Variable(1.0, name='var1')
   ...: 
   ...: with tf.variable_scope(ms1.original_name_scope) as ms2:
   ...:   tf.Variable(2.0, name='var2')
   ...: 
   ...: print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])
   ...: 
['myscope/var1/initial_value', 
 'myscope/var1', 
 'myscope/var1/Assign', 
 'myscope/var1/read', 
 'myscope/var2/initial_value', 
 'myscope/var2', 
 'myscope/var2/Assign', 
 'myscope/var2/read']
```

**Remark**
Please also note that setting `reuse=True` is optional; That is, even if you pass `reuse=True`, you'd still get the same result.

---

Another way (thanks to OP himself!) is to just add `/` at the end of the variable scope when *reusing* it as in the following example:

```
In [13]: with tf.variable_scope('myscope'):
    ...:   tf.Variable(1.0, name='var1')
    ...: 
    ...: # reuse variable scope by appending `/` to the target variable scope
    ...: with tf.variable_scope('myscope/', reuse=True):
    ...:   tf.Variable(2.0, name='var2')
    ...: 
    ...: print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])
    ...: 
['myscope/var1/initial_value', 
 'myscope/var1', 
 'myscope/var1/Assign', 
 'myscope/var1/read', 
 'myscope/var2/initial_value', 
 'myscope/var2', 
 'myscope/var2/Assign', 
 'myscope/var2/read']
```

**Remark**:
     Please note that setting `reuse=True` is again optional; That is, even if you pass `reuse=True`, you'd still get the same result.

Comment: `var2` is not under `myscope`, am I missing something?

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's a way for me query tensorflow for `ms1` in this example? In my actual usage, I didn't create the original variable scope, it was created for me within tensorflow and I'm actually just trying to add some variables to that scope. This is part of an implementation of an optimizer and tensorflow handles some of the scoping in a way that didn't get handled by the framework for one detail of my use case. If not don't worry, there's an alternate way to deal with it.

Comment: Ah, you can just use `tf.variable_scope('myscope/'):` in lieu of `tf.variable_scope(ms1.original_name_scope)` I hadn't known that using the '/' was necessary. Now it all makes good sense! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Answer mentioned by kmario23 is correct but there is a tricky case with variables created by `tf.get_variable`:

```
with tf.variable_scope('myscope'):
    print(tf.get_variable('var1', shape=[3]))

with tf.variable_scope('myscope/'):
    print(tf.get_variable('var2', shape=[3]))
```

This snippet will output:

```
<tf.Variable 'myscope/var1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'myscope//var2:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

It seems that `tensorflow` has not provided a formal way to handle this circumstance yet. The only possible method I found is to manually assign the correct name (**Warning: The correctness is not guaranteed**):

```
with tf.variable_scope('myscope'):
    print(tf.get_variable('var1', shape=[3]))

with tf.variable_scope('myscope/') as scope:
    scope._name = 'myscope'
    print(tf.get_variable('var2', shape=[3]))
```

And then we can get the correct names:

```
<tf.Variable 'myscope/var1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'myscope/var2:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>
```